# How to find entered, exited data in d3 without using DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Let's assuma I have two arrays

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
a2 = [1,3,4,5,6];
```

I want to know which one is entered (6) and which one is exited (2) in this array.

D3 has it's own functions `enter()`, `exit()` but they work on DOM.

Can I just simply use it without appending, removing any HTML elements?

Comment: How do you know whether one has been entered or exited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as far as I see, there is no shortcut in D3 for this kind of operation. Therefore, I used a jQuery based solution. For future references, I'm sharing it here.

```
Array.prototype.findDiff = function(that) {
    return {
        exit: $(this).not(that).get(),
        enter: $(that).not(this).get()
    };
};
```

So,

`[0,1,2,3,4].findDiff([1,2,3,4,5])`

will give

```
{
    "exit": [
        0
    ],
    "enter": [
        5
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.enter()` and `.exit()` functions operate on selections, which are collections of DOM elements. In order to use them, you have to select elements, so it doesn't make much sense to use them without adding or removing and DOM elements.

For your data with the default key function, nothing would be in the enter or exit selections if `a1` was the data bound to the DOM elements and you matched `a2` to it (or vice versa) as the two arrays have the same length. By default, D3 matches data based on the array index.

Comment: "By default, D3 matches data based on the array index." but if I use `selection.data(someData, function(d,i){return d})` it matches content itself so that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case you're giving D3 a key function that tells it how to match.